# Can I use different validation method to compare with other paper?

Tags: deep-learning

I want to write a academic paper which use the open dataset. I find the author of this dataset and some researchers use 10-fold cross validation, and other researchers don't tell which validation and test method they used. So I am not sure what I should use.

Can I use train test split method to compare with the accuracy of other paper? For example, 70% train set, 15% validation set and 15% test set.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no, using different generalisation estimation is not gonna yield statistically sounds results. If authors claim that they used 10-fold cross validation and you want to compare against them there are just two options:

1. Use 10-fold cross validation with your method (yes, splits will be different, but 10-fold cross validation is relatively strong estimator for reasonably big datasets, as opposed to 15% single split)
2. Reimplement other method and use your evaluation scheme on it.

Note that in case of 2 using just 15% data points for evaluation makes sense **only** if you have lots of data (as a rule of thumbs sth around >70,000 points so that 15% is actually 10,000 samples)

Comment: At first, thank you very much for your reply. But I don't understand what other methods mean. Can you specify it?

Comment: By "other method" I mean the methods described in the papers you want to compare against. Comparison based on just copying someones numbers from the table is justified only if evaluation protocol matches exactly. Otherwise you need to implement (and train) the baseline methods yourself, and then you are free to choose evaluation scheme